# Take all tweets from a user

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-r

I try this to take all the tweets from a user:

```
library(twitteR)
library(RSQLite)
api_key <- '' #set the credentials
api_secret <- ''
access_token <- ''
access_token_secret <- ''

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
register_sqlite_backend("sqlit_file")
#n = search_twitter_and_store("#rstats", "rstats_tweets")
n = search_twitter_and_store("from:hadleywickham", "rstats_tweets")
```

It is from a specific user. As I can see from the twitter profilr 29700 tweets but n is 0 instead of having the 29700 tweets.

What am I doing wrong in the process.

Comment: The package `rtweet` is a little more up to date I believe and more convenient to use: https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet

Comment: Your code is working for me. What happens when you run
 `dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="sqlit_file")` ?